# Is it possible to add a variable "embedded variables" to a struct?

Tags: go, struct, types

```
type UserModel struct {
    ...
}

func (u *UserModel) C() string {
    return "system_users"
}
```

The above will assign an embedded struct to the type `UserModel`, does Go allow the same to be done with `var`s or `const`s?

Something like

```
var (u *UserModel) C = "system_users"
```

You get the idea.

Comment: How is the aboveassign an embedded struct to the tyoe `UserModel` ?

Comment: Your code just defines a type and adds a method for that type. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types for the definition of struct types and embedded fields.

Comment: This question could be the down vote champion Х) There is no embedding. It is a struct with a method. It is possible to define methods for other types.

Comment: @I159 I guess it's too tedious to type something like "ohh dude, those are called methods, not "embedded structs". lol noob" K, thanks

Comment: @borislemke, do you still need an answer about methods definition for different types?

Comment: @I159 let me do the walk of shame with this question, probably deserved it

Answer (score 2):

#### Methods

Methods is a functions with receivers bound to a types. Receiver could take a value or a pointer to a type which method bound to.

Go by example provides this nice [example](https://play.golang.org/p/254m_9Yjwa):

```
type rect struct {
    width, height int
}

// This `area` method has a _receiver type_ of `*rect`.
func (r *rect) area() int {
    return r.width * r.height
}

// Methods can be defined for either pointer or value
// receiver types. Here's an example of a value receiver.
func (r rect) perim() int {
    return 2*r.width + 2*r.height
}
```

And yes you can define methods on almost all existing types except `interface`. Also it must be local type (defined in a package not built-in)

```
type Int int

func (i Int) Add(j Int) Int {
    return i + j
}
```

#### Embedding

Generalizing "Effective Go" a bit:

The methods of embedded types come along for free. Which means that if type B embedded to type A than type A not only has its own methods it also has methods of type B.

Extending previous example:

```
type parallelogram struct {
    rect // Embedding. parallelogram has area and perim methods
    depth int
}

func (p parallelogram) volume () int { // Extending rect
    // Volume logic
}
```